# Select all data including null if the SQL variable is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have to run a query in SQL Server 2012 to select data from the table. There is a variable `@status`. If this variable is null then all the data must be returned else if value

I have a sample query for this

```
SELECT * 
FROM StatusTable 
WHERE (Status = IIF(@status IS NULL, status, @status))
```

This query works fine when `@status` is not null but when it is null, it return only the rows where the status column is not null.

Sample table:

```
| id | status | Data |
|----|--------|------|
| 1  | null   | a    |
| 2  | ok     | b    |
| 3  | fail   | c    |
| 4  | fail   | d    |
| 5  | null   | e    |
```

when `@status` is "fail":

```
| id | status | Data |
|----|--------|------|
| 3  | fail   | c    |
| 4  | fail   | d    |
```

But when `@status` is null, it returns:

```
| id | status | Data |
|----|--------|------|
| 2  | ok     | b    |
| 3  | fail   | c    |
| 4  | fail   | d    |
```

Kindly help, Thanks

PS: in case of null status, I want the whole (sample) table to be returned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `or`:

```
SELECT *
FROM StatusTable
WHERE (Status = @Status or @Status IS NULL);
```

Comment: I understand this style of query will result in suboptimal execution plans.

Comment: @Dai, if you add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` ([and you should add this option to this kind of query](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html)), then execution plan will always be optimal.

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu, with `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`, if the value of the `@Status` variable is NULL, optimiser would remove the whole `WHERE` condition from the query. As if there was no `WHERE` at all. If `@Status` is not NULL, optimiser would look at available statistics for the specific given non-NULL value of the parameter and make a decision what is better - scan or seek.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Please excuse my rant, somehow I didn't see the `@` symbol in front of the `@Status IS NULL` and confused it with `Status IS NULL`.

Comment: Hi, this query works perfectly however, I was looking for a query which is a bit faster, somewhat on the lines of `CASE ..WHEN..THERE..END`